# Get last observable data from request

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

I built a simple small angular web app that the user can enter a store number then scan an UPC with a handheld scanner and it will display the item descript picture and price of the item. When they type in the upc this works as expected always but when I scan a upc number it sometimes brings back the error request instead of the good request because I think it is just going to fast. Does anyone know how to return just the last observable?

this is my ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {IroService} from './iro.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-iro',
  templateUrl: './iro.component.html',
  providers: [IroService],
  styleUrls: ['./iro.component.scss']
})
export class IroAppComponent {
  title = 'app';
    countrys = [
      {value: 'US', viewValue: 'US'}
  ];
  public iroDatas;
  public hidIroData = true;
  public productName;
  public productPic;
  public IroError = true;
  public status;
  public iroPrice;
  constructor(private _iroService: IroService) {

  }
    getIroData(upc: number, storeNum: number) {
    this._iroService.getIroData(upc, storeNum).subscribe(res => {
         if (res.status !== 'error') {
          this.productName = res.payload[0].productOffersWrapper.product.productName;
          this.productPic = res.payload[0].productOffersWrapper.entityAssetGroups[0].entityAssetList[0].assetUrl;
          this.hidIroData = false;
          this.IroError = true;
          this.iroPrice = res.payload[0].productOffersWrapper.offerWrappers[0].storeFronts[0].offerPricing.storefrontPricingList[0].
          currentPrice.currentValue.currencyAmount;
         }else {
             this.IroError = false;
             this.hidIroData = true;
         }
    })
  }
}
```

this is my service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/distinctUntilChanged';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/filter';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';

@Injectable()
export class IroService {
    private headers = new Headers({ 'content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' });
    private options = new RequestOptions({headers: this.headers});
    private iroUrl = 'http://pos-oe-service.prod.poscloud-orchestration.rscte.prod.walmart.com/iro2/';

    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    getIroData(upc, storeNum) {
        return this.http.get(this.iroUrl + upc + '/' + storeNum, this.options)
        .map((res: any) => res.json().shareReplay(1))
        //.catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(`Network Error: ${error.statusText} (${error.status})`));
        .catch((error: Response) => [{status: 'error'}]);
    }
```

this is my html

```
<app-iro-header></app-iro-header>
<div class="container">
    <div id="storeNum">
    <md-input-container class="iro-full-width">
    <input type="search" (keyup.enter)="getIroData(upc.value,storeNum.value)" #storeNum mdInput placeholder="Store Number" required>
    </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <div id="upc">
        <md-input-container class="iro-full-width">
        <input type="search" (keyup.enter)="getIroData(upc.value,storeNum.value)" (input)="getIroData(upc.value,storeNum.value)" #upc mdInput placeholder="UPC" required>
        </md-input-container>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="country">
        <md-select placeholder="Country" name="country">
            <md-option id="countryOption" *ngFor="let country of countrys" [value]="country.value">
                {{country.viewValue}}
            </md-option>
        </md-select>
        </div>
    <div>
   <button md-raised-button color="primary" id="Search" (click)="getIroData(upc.value,storeNum.value)" type="button">Search</button> 
    </div>
    <div id="data" [hidden]="hidIroData">
      <h1 class="productName">{{productName}}</h1>
      <img class="productImage" src="{{productPic}}" height="200" width="200">
      <h1 class="priceName" color="primary"> Price  {{iroPrice | currency: 'USD':true}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="error" [hidden]="IroError">
        <h1 class="productError">No data for this upc at this store number</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sometimes this works and it returns the product information as expected but sometimes it returns the item for a second then immediately shows the error message of item not found. I know the last request from the observable is good by looking at chrome developer tools but I do not know how to make it wait and always return the last observable Thank you for your help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScVUN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what I have done in this situation is handle the status code or return some headers in an if statement in your

```
getIroData(upc: number, storeNum: number) {
    this._iroService.getIroData(upc, storeNum).subscribe(res => {
         if (res.status !== 'error') {
```

I would check for more errors that you could handle

```
 if (res.status !== 'error' || res.status !== 'not found' || res.httpStatusCode !== 404) {
```

do something like this